# How to display username after login in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
       if (!IsPostBack)
           {
                if (Session["UserName"] != null)
                {
                    this.lblWelcomeMessage.Text = string.Format("Welcome {0}", Session["UserName"].ToString());
                }
            }
```

> I want to add username after longin..How will i display username

Answer (score 2):

After Authenticating User login credentials, first you need to save username to session
Like: `Session["UserName"] = UserName;`

Then on welcome page,
welcome.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lb1.Text = "<b><font color=Brown>" + "WELCOME  " + 
               "</font>" + "<b><font color=red>" + 
                Session["UserName"] + "</font>";         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbox -> Access -> Login Name

Put it into asp page and it display the name of the logged in user.

Comment: display as a welcome user

Comment: Display the username wich you are log in, you can write what you want before and after the object

Comment: Isn't it what do you want ?